# i have trouble with printing an array after reading it in JAVA

Tags: java, printing

i have problem with printing the array after reading it. After printing, the address of memory is printed, not value of the array. What can i do for that ?

```
public class MyClass
{
     Student St = new Student();

     Student[]Array1 = new Student[10];


     void AddList()
     {

            Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            for (int i=0; i<Array1.length & i<ArrayF1.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Student NAME Number " + (i+1) + ":");
                Array1[i] = new Student();
                Array1[i].setName(Scan.next());


                //System.out.println("Enter Student MARK Number " + (i+1) + ":");
                //St.setMark(Scan.nextFloat());
            }

    }
```

this is my print method. The result of print is like this

(studentproject.Student@1a758cb)

```
 void PrintList()
 {

            for (int i=0; i<Array1.length; i++)
            {

                System.out.println(Array1[i]);

            }
 }
```

this is my Student Class that i have all my setter and getter method on that ... So i have 3 Class how can i work with this 3 class and in one of them get the data and in another print the Mark data and in third class print the Student Name data  ... how can i do that ... i do some code but i dont know is it correct or not ... thanks for your help ...

```
public class Student
{
private String Name;
private float Mark;

/**
 * @return the Name
 */
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

/**
 * @param Name the Name to set
 */
public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
}

/**
 * @return the Mark
 */
public float getMark() {
    return Mark;
}

/**
 * @param Mark the Mark to set
 */
public void setMark(float Mark) {
    this.Mark = Mark;
}

}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+array+tostring You see, it has nothing to do with reading student names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just override the `toString()` method in `Student` class, and return the appropriate string you want to get printed when you print an instance.

It may look like: -

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + studentName;
}
```

Currently, the default implementation of `toString()` method of `Object` class is invoked, and what you are seeing is the format returned from that method, which is of the form - `Type@hashCode`

Comment: May you tell me what exactly i have to write ?

Comment: @user1935321.. If you google search with the content - `Overriding toString in Java`, you will get immense information and examples regarding that. Still I'll add one small example here.

Comment: this is my Student Class that i have all my setter and getter method on that ... So i have 3 Class how can i work with this 3 class and in one of them get the data and in another print the Mark data and in third class print the Student Name data  ... how can i do that ... i do some code but i dont know is it correct or not ... thanks for your help ...

Comment: @user1935321.. If you want to print separate data, then you need to invoke the `getters` explicitly. Like - `array1.getName()`, and `array1.getMark();`. And please use Java naming conventions. Your variable name should start with lowercase alphabets.

Comment: i put the codes of my Student class .. and you can see the MyClass Class and also i have a Calculate Class for calculate the avreage of the mark for student ... how can i work with 3 class ... thanks alot ...

Comment: @user1935321.. You need to pass the array as method parameter in the method of `Calculate` class from your `MyClass`, where you are creating your array. And then in `Calculate` class, iterate over your array, and invoke `array[i].getName()` to print the name of each student.

Comment: My problem is printing the Array dosent work and print something else other than value of Array as i said to you before ... with tree class how can i solve the printing in MyClass class in method PrintList ...

Comment: What are you printing? Are you printing just `Array1`?

Comment: i want to print Array1 and ArrayF1 first for Student name and Second for Student Mark ... but my printing doesnt work ... if the printing the Array work i can pass the array to another class and method ...

Answer (score 0):

Here I've added some stuff how `toString()` method can be override

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int id;
    float mark;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(float mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student[ID:" + id + ",Name:" + name + ",Mark:"+mark+"]";
    }

    public void printStudentInfo() {
        // print all the details of student
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] students = new Student[10];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Student Name " + (i + 1) + ":");
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            Student student = new Student(name, i + 1);
            System.out.println("Enter Student MARK Number " + (i + 1) + ":");
            float mark = scanner.nextFloat();
            student.setMark(mark);
            students[i]=student;
        }
        for(Student student:students) {
            // by default toStirng method is called
            System.out.println(student);
            //or you can call like
            //student.printStudentInfo();
        }
    }
}
```